# Continuous Deployment & Live Updates not happening in ionic appflow with successfully build & deploy

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, continuous-deployment, ionic-appflow

I have configured the app in the the ionic dashboard, syncing with GitHub, when I commit it shows in the ionic dashboard, I can successfully build and deploy using the master channel. But not getting changes in my running app. Thank you.

config.xml:-

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^5.4.5">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="e9c5****" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Master" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="auto" />
        <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
        <variable name="MIN_BACKGROUND_DURATION" value="30" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
  </plugin>
```

ionic.config.json:-

```
{
  "name": "appFlowLatestTest",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "angular",
  "id": "e9c5****"
}
```

package.json:-

```
"cordova-plugin-ionic": {
        "APP_ID": "e9c5****",
        "CHANNEL_NAME": "Master",
        "UPDATE_METHOD": "auto",
        "MAX_STORE": "2",
        "MIN_BACKGROUND_DURATION": "30",
        "UPDATE_API": "https://api.ionicjs.com"
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up this step like this?

Example

```
ionic deploy add \
--app-id="999999999" \
--channel-name="Master" \
--update-method="auto"
```